# how to pass the variable in jquery click event function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to Pass the variable with click event in jquery

```
var get=3; 
$('#edit').click(function(event){
alert('You are getting:' + get);
}
```

please help me

html

```
<input type='submit' name='action' id='edit' />
```

Comment: to where you want to pass the data?

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize click even once document is loaded. Also you have syntax error in your code.

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get=3;
    $('#edit').click(function(event){
        alert('You are getting:' + get);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var get=3;
        $('#edit').click(function(event){
            alert('You are getting:' + get);
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='submit' name='action' id='edit' />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the closing paranthesis.

Your javascript code should look like:

```
var get=3; 
$('#edit').click(function(event){
  alert('You are getting:' + get);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML button

```
<button id='my_button' type='button' data-id='1' data-values='1' value='6' data-whatever='20'>My button</button>
```

Jquery

```
$('#my_button').bind('click', function() {
    var value = $(this)val();
    var whatever = $(this).data('whatever');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var values = $(this).data('values');
    console.log(value);
    console.log(whatever);
    console.log(id);
    console.log(values);

});
```

1. Open Firefox > Inspect Element > Console Tab.
2. Load the codes
3. Click the button
4. See response

Answer (score 1):

Initiate everything after document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get = 3; 
    $('#edit').click(function(event){
        alert('You are getting:' + get);
    });
});
```

also don't use event handlers until you need it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get=3; 
    $('#edit').on('click', function(event){
        alert('You are getting:' + get);
   }
});
```

html:

```
<input type="button" id="edit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var get = 3;
    $("#edit" ).bind("click", { key: get }, function(event){
        // event.data.key will have value of get
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function test(ev) {
    var id = $(ev).attr('id');
    alert(id);
  }
</script>


<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" OnClick="test(this);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

html:

```
<input type="button" id="edit"><br/>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var get = 3;  
    $("#edit").on('click',function(){ 
        alert("Value is: " + get); 
        //parameter value
    }); 
});
```